# Importing custom Javascript using import maps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I'm trying to start a project in Rails 7 using import maps to handle Javascript. I'm able to import jQuery and jquery-ui, but I'm having trouble importing my own custom file. My directory structure looks like this:

```
app
└── javascript
  ├── application.js
  └── things
    └── main.js
```

**importmap.rb**

```
pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.js"
pin "jquery-ui", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery-ui@1.13.2/ui/widget.js"

pin "application" #, preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/things"
```

**bin/importmap json**

```
{
  "imports": {
    "jquery": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-ui": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery-ui@1.13.2/ui/widget.js",
    "application": "/assets/application-96f4674148ca000af60a0849c2131544545b3b328a53205668f7e25bc48703b7.js",
    "main": "/main.js"
  }
}
```

**application.js:**

```
import "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";

console.log('hello');

import "main";
```

**main.js:**

```
console.log('hello again');
```

When I comment out the `import "main"` line in application.js, I see the debug statement "hello" in the console. But when I uncomment it, I get nothing, no error message either. I can't make my JS any simpler, but I have no idea what's causing it to fail. Also is there a way to get any more info about the failure? (error messages, logs, etc)

Comment: `pin_all_from "app/javascript/things", under: "things"` and `import "things/main"`

Comment: @Alex that did the trick - thanks for your help! You've helped me a few times in this process and I really appreciate it :)